# Certificado de constitución o registro / Certificado de cumplimiento / Extracto del registro comercial google play

Tags: google-play

estoy intentando crear una cuenta de desarrollo en Google Play (mi pais es Argentina), y me esta pidiendo alguno de los siguientes documentos:

Certificado de constitución o registro
Certificado de cumplimiento
Extracto del registro comercial

Alguien podria decirme como consigo eso, o a que hacen referencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]